# Add new function in promise.all runtime in node

Tags: asynchronous, promise, async-await, synchronous

I am not sure about this question if this can be implemented or not.

I am using node.js with express.js and MySQL database.

I have a few records in MySQL database. These records are updating continues.

So, suppose I fetch some records from MySQL and start operations on each record with `Promise.all` using `demoFunction` function which is returned promise.

In this function, I am trying to check for new records in MySQL database. If I got new records then I want to push this new record's operation into current `Promise.all` queue. Is this possible? If not possible then how can I achieve this goal with continues execution?

So, my code is like,

```
const demoFunction = (arg1, arg2) => {
    checkForNewData();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Rest of my code is here for this function
        // This function will be take around 5 to 10 mins    
    });
};

const dataFromDatabase = "Here i'm getting some data into array of object from SQL database";

let allPromises = dataFromDatabase.map((obj) => demoFunction(obj.arg1, obj.arg1));

const checkForNewData = () => {
    const newDataFromDatabase = "Here i'm getting some new data into array of object from SQL database";

    for (let i = 0; i < newDataFromDatabase.length; i++) {
        allPromises.push(demoFunction(newDataFromDatabase[i].arg1, newDataFromDatabase[i].arg2));
    }
};

return Promise.all(allPromises)
    .then(() => {
        // response
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    })
```

Comment: What are `dataFromDatabase` and `newDataFromDatabase`? Promises?

Answer (score 0):

> In this function, I am trying to check for new records in MySQL database. If I got new records then I want to push this new record's operation into current Promise.all queue. Is this possible?

Nope, `Promise.all` takes a finite and set number of promises and waits for all of them to complete.

> If not possible then how can I achieve this goal with continues execution?

Well, a promise is just a value - if you have a promise for something then execution has already started somewhere else. You can always execute a second `.all` but what happens if records were added in the meantime?

It's fine to do:

```
Promise.all(allPromises).then(() => Promise.all(allPromises)).then(() => {

});
```

But at that point you're better off just waiting for the `checkNewData` call to finish before calling the `Promise.all` since otherwise you're introducing a race between checkAllData and the Promise.all

---

A promise is a "one time" thing, consider using an async iterator if you want to process results (note, this requires Node 12):

```
async function* getRecordData() {
  for await(const item in getPromisesOfInitDataFromDatabase()) {
    yield item; // or process it
  }
  while(true) { // or how often you want
    for await(const item of getNewDastaFromDatabase()) {
      yield item; // or process it
    }
    await sleep(3000); // or some sleep timeout to not constantly poll
  }
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
(async () => {
  for await(const item of getRecordData()) {
    // items are available here one by one, including new items in the database
  }
})();
```